# jquery and ajax repeating call

Tags: jquery

I have a single page app, that uses generic handlers and jquery.

The first time the page runs, the update database function gets called.  second time it is called, the update database function gets called twice, the third time is is called, the update database function gets called three times...   This continues as many times as the update modal form is accessed and closed.   so if i edit 15 records, the update jquery function gets called 15 times.

I have ensured there is no code looping logic, it is a single click event that calls the update function... so i am thinking that it is the event bubbling stuff.

Why would the update function get called again for each previous edit, thus doing an accumulative error.

I am adding the click handler after the display area is built up...

```
  $('#SavePermitEdit').click(function(event) {
  var passthis = record[0];
  SavePermitEditHandler(passthis);
  event.stopPropagation();
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

duh - i found it....

I needed to perform an unbind() before i bound a new click....

```
  $('#SavePermitEdit').unbind();

  $('#SavePermitEdit').click(function(event) {
  var passthis = record[0];
  SavePermitEditHandler(passthis);
  event.stopPropagation();
  });
```